# Problem in implementing jquery and MotoTools together?

Tags: jquery

I am developing a website in which I am implementing two sliders for image galleries, one with jQuery and the other with MooTools. But there is problem in implementing these because when i use both together the jQuery silder doesn't works where MooTools slider does. jQuery slider works in case where I remove MooTools. What should I do to implement both sliders together? Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the noConflict mode for jQuery and then you can use jQuery instead of $ or use a closure like this to get back the $ you are used to :

```
(function($){
    // Some code
})(jQuery);
```

See : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
jQuery.noConflict();

// jQuery() = jQuery
// $() = MooTools
```

I had to use this method for [this performance test](http://jsperf.com/inserting-elements-jquery-vs-mootools)